# How to monitor drive failures via IPMI/Redfish Supermicro & Gigabyte

Tags: ssd, raid, monitoring, ipmi

We have a bunch of Supermicro SuperServers deployed (various generations) and since we had a few drive (SSD) failures in the last month. We only noticed the failures (depending on the RAID level) either by passing by the server and seeing the LED blink or the node being down.
Is there an automated (IPMI/Redfish) way to monitor the drive state as shown in the web interface?
So far I haven't found any query in `ipmitool` that gives me any information on the drive state.

Similar question for Gigabyte servers as we will be getting a few storage servers soon (RAID 6).

Comment: [Supermicro IPMI Utilities](https://www.supermicro.com/en/solutions/management-software/ipmi-utilities) - would `smcipmitool` work? I've never used it, but it does have `hdd` and `nvme` commands

Comment: Any luck with this? I have been looking for any lead and tested every IPMI tool to get disks info that I see on the BMC UI without luck

Comment: I'm also not sure where to download the `smcipmitool`